# Unable to synchronized app import configuration failed

Tags: magento2, upgrade

hi guys i am facing this issue `(The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.)`

i want to run upgrade command but whenever i do it says hash has not been saved ,please re run di compile command , i pursue the error in deep and conclude in point that my app/etc/config file are unable to synchronize or update .

That's how my error log looks like :

> {"0":"The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or
>   setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.","1":"#0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(121):
>   Magento\Deploy\Model\Plugin\ConfigChangeDetector->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\module-page-cache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin.php(73):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(135):
>   Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
>   Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor.php(26):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
>   Array, Array)\n#5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(135):
>   Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chase\index.php(41):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))\n#8
>   {main}","url":"/chase/admin","script_name":"/chase/index.php"}

and this error appears on console : 
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens after you change `app/etc/config.php` file.
You need to reimport configurations from `app/etc/config.php` file to your database by running the below command.

```
php bin/magento app:config:import
```

Comment: you're right but in my case i was running this import command first than upgrade which was creating this hash issue , after fresh install if i skip this config import command and runs only upgrade it works for me. but i consider your answer correct for others

Comment: I was having the same issue. tried above command and it worked for me. thanks