# Magento 2.2.2 error: The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration

Tags: database, configuration, magento2.2.2, localhost

I am getting this error when attempting to install Magento locally:

> The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or
>   setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.

When running "app:config:import" nothing is resolved, when running "setup:upgrade" it runs and then fails towards the end with the following reason:

> Import failed: Hash has not been saved.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am running in my local environment in "Default" mode.

Comment: Can you rerun your commands adding `-vvv` at the end, for verbosity of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried below command ?? if no then try once.

```
php bin/magento app:config:import
```

for more details >> [Unable to synchronized app import configuration failed](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208860/unable-to-synchronized-app-import-configuration-failed)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a fresh install, please ignore app:config:import command.

Or if this is not a new install, then please check that the below two files have the correct permissions and check all the modules are listed correctly on the config.php file.

```
These are two files path.
app/etc/env.php
app/etc/config.php
```